# How to write Bash script What is the command to open a terminal with two different tabed terminals and execute some commands separately tabs?

Tags: bash, scripts, gnome-terminal

How to write Bash script to open a terminal with two tabs, and execute commands in both tabs?

for instance: 
tab 1 opens skype
tab 2 opens chromium-browser

In the end, I want one more thing: write a bash script with my skype username and password and feed those to skype.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want a script which opens two terminals for you? Or should the script open skype and chromium? (I will edit your question later to make it understandable).

Comment: Done , i edited it

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it, especially the last part. Please try to explain why you need the terminals. Bash does not need terminals to execute the commands.

Comment: I never heard the word "taped" in conjunction with "terminal" -- can you explain what a "taped terminal" is? Terminal in most cases refers to a terminal emulator or virtual console.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

one terminal with **two tabs**:

```
gnome-terminal --tab --tab
```

use the -e switch to execute commands (or scripts):

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "command1" --tab -e "command2"
```

(I don't think there is an easy way of feeding your credentials to skype via the terminal.)
**Update**: check w4YGcbTeIH's answer, skype allows giving credentials via the command line.

But **beware**, your credentials would be exposed and this should be avoided.

A script to open skype and chromium-browser would look like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

skype --dbpath=<path> &
chromium-browser &
```

Put this code into `myscript.sh` and execute `chmod +x myscript.sh` (in a terminal) to make it executable.

About **skype**:

- you can run skype without arguments (`skype &`) and it will load your default user profile `~/.Skype`.
- run it with `--dbpath=<path>` where `<path>` is your actual path of the Skype profile you want skype to load.

To **run the script** do one of the following:

- open a terminal and execute `./myscript.sh`
- double click on the script and choose *Run* in the dialog.

Comment: Once you have the bash script it will be executed by /bin/bash, there is no terminal in the game.
What do you mean taped?  I have never heard that word.

Comment: I edited my answer. gnome-terminal& is the command to open a terminal on a gnome desktop.

Comment: gnome-terminal --tab --tab is the command two have to tabs. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: I think all is in my answer now, use the -e to execute commands. As for skype, I don't think it is possible what you are asking. I suggest you play around and get more familiar with bash by reading tutorials. Also make use of the man command.

Comment: Could you add a way to keep the terminal open after the script is run?

Comment: @jcollum : there might be a way but I don't know it.

Comment: @rosch: How could i launch the tab in the same terminal window? --tab arg will launch terminal in a new window.

Comment: We may need a new answer soon: _# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.#_

Answer (score 1):

```
$ skype -h
Skype 4.0.0.8

Usage: skype [options]
Options:
  --dbpath=<path>       Specify an alternative path to store Skype data files.
                        Default: ~/.Skype
  --resources=<path>    Specify a path where Skype can find its resource files.
                        Default: /usr/share/skype
  --disable-api         Disable Skype Public API.
  --callto <nick>
  skype:<nick>?<action>
                        These commands allow Skype links handling.
  --pipelogin           Command line login. "echo username password | skype --pipelogin"
  --version             Display version information and exit.
```

**echo username password | skype --pipelogin** does what you want, but as rosch said : "Also, your credentials would be exposed and this should be avoided."
They would be exposed on the **history** of the shell :

```
$ echo user pass | skype --pipelogin
[...]
$ history
[...]
 2006  echo user pass | skype --pipelogin
 2007  history
$
```

Comment: You should write another question for this otherwise good answer. :)