# A bash script that opens several terminals from different direcotories and operates some funtions on those terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Maybe my question was partly answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203494/how-to-write-bash-script-what-is-the-command-to-open-a-terminal-with-two-differe) but I need full solution.

What I want to do is this:

`gnome-terminal --tab -x "cd /ini/experiments/ gedit mytext.txt" --tab -e "cd /ini/myex/ipython"`

So I need to execute `ipython` from `myex` diretory and open `mytext.txt` from experiments directory. Since I have several such jobs every time, it is headache to do.

I tried this as well: `gnome-terminal --tab  --working-directory="/ini/experiments/ gedit mytext.txt"` but this does not work, it gets to home directory again.

Many thanks

Comment: Where is located `ini` directory? Is it really in `/` -root directory or in your home directory?

Answer (score 0):

If those paths to the directories are corrects as you say, then you should use:

```
gnome-terminal --tab -e "bash -c 'cd /ini/experiments/ && gedit mytext.txt';$SHELL" --tab -e "bash -c 'cd /ini/myex/ipython';$SHELL"
```

See also:

- [`man gnome-terminal`](http://csurs7.csr.uky.edu/cgi-bin/man/man2html?1%20x-terminal-emulator)
- [How to run a script without closing the terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/20330/147044)