# How to automatically opening terminal windows & tabs, ssh and sudo su?

Tags: command-line, ssh, sudo, gnome-terminal, workspaces

When I start my day in front of my computer, I first have to do the following:

- In workspace 1:

  - Open a new terminal window, `ssh loginserver`, then `ssh serverA1` and `sudo su account00`
  - Open a new terminal tab, `ssh loginserver`, then `ssh serverA2` and `sudo su account00`
  - Open a new terminal tab, `ssh loginserver`, then `ssh serverA3` and `sudo su account00`
- In workspace 2:

  - Open a new terminal window, 1`ssh loginserver`, then `ssh serverB1` and `sudo su account00`
  - Open a new terminal tab, `ssh loginserver`, then `ssh serverB2` and `sudo su account00`
  - Open a new terminal tab, `ssh loginserver`, then `ssh serverB3` and `sudo su account00`
- In workspace 3:

  - etc...

Is there a way to automatize the whole process, e.g., having a script that automatically opens each terminal window in its own workspace, all terminal tabs in each window, and all corresponding `ssh` / `sudo su` commands? If not, which parts can I automatize?

Comment: May **`xdotool`** help.

Comment: Maybe http://askubuntu.com/a/446065/16395 can give some hint...

Answer (score 1):

I would use a bash script for each workspace and add the commands there.

that's the basic idea, then you can add commands like [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/203499/10698), where you start a new terminal and run some commands.

and just update your bash file which should be like this filename.sh and mark it executable so you can launch it by just double clicking it.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138430/30041) could help you launch your commands in a new workspace.